# Java Game Programming Part 2: Disappearing Images

Tags: java, swing, pacman

For a school computer project I decided make a Pac-Man style game in Java (with two other people). None of us have much experience, so we've essentially been teaching ourselves up to this point. We've made quite a bit of progress, but we seem to have reached a standstill at this point.

How can we make the candies disappear when Fatman runs over them? We've tried using repaint, but we can't seem to get things to work properly.

(I have other things I need help on but they are in different questions)

Thank you for your help!

Here is our code so far:

**Maze Class:**

```
package Fatman;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Maze {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Maze();
    }

    public Maze(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Fatman!");
        f.add(new Board());
        f.setSize(816, 838);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**Map Class**

```
    package Fatman;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Map {

    private Scanner m;
    private String Map[] = new String[25]; 

    private Image spaceregcandy,
                  srcb,
                  safehouse,
                  spacebigcandy,
                  blackspace,
                  space,
                  portal1,
                  portal2,
                  wall;

    public Map(){

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\spaceregcandy.png");
        spaceregcandy = img.getImage();
        //image icon has already been initiated, so it doesn't have to be written again
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\spaceregcandyblue.png");
        srcb = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\safehouse.png");
        safehouse = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\wall232x.png");
        wall = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\spacebigcandy.png");
        spacebigcandy = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\blackspace.png");
        blackspace = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\space.png");
        space = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\portal1.png");
        portal1 = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\portal2.png");
        portal2 = img.getImage();

        openFile();
        readFile();
        closeFile();
        }

    public Image getSpaceregcandy(){
        return spaceregcandy;
    }
    public Image getSrcb(){
        return srcb;
    }
    public Image getSafehouse(){
        return safehouse;
    }
    public Image getWall(){
        return wall;
    }
    public Image getSpacebigcandy(){
        return spacebigcandy;
    }
    public Image getBlackspace(){
        return blackspace;
    }
    public Image getSpace(){
        return space;
    }
    public Image getPortal1(){
        return portal1;
    }
    public Image getPortal2(){
        return portal2;
    }

    public String getMap(int x, int y){
        String index = Map[y].substring(x, x + 1);
        return index;
        //in y position, if y = 2, goes to second row (substring gets x position)
    }

    public void openFile(){

        try{
        m = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\map3.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error loading map");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        while(m.hasNext()){
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
                Map[i] = m.next();
            }
        }

    }

    public void closeFile(){
        m.close();
    }
}
```

**Board Class**

```
package Fatman;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Timer timer;

    private Image player;

    private Map m;
    private Player p;

    public Board(){

        m = new Map();
        p = new Player();
        addKeyListener(new Al());
        setFocusable(true);
        timer = new Timer(1, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        repaint();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);

        for(int y = 0; y < 25; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x <25; x++){
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("o")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSpaceregcandy(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("O")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSrcb(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("x")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getWall(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("H")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSafehouse(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }   
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("C")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSpacebigcandy(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("b")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getBlackspace(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("s")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSpace(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("p")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getPortal1(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("P")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getPortal2(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
        }


    }


        g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(), p.getTileX() * 32, p.getTileY() * 32, null);

}

    public class Al extends KeyAdapter{

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() -1).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() -1).equals("b")){                       
                        }
                        p.move(0, -1);                  

                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));

            }
                }

            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() +1).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() +1).equals("b")){
                        p.move(0, 1);
                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));
            }
                }
            }
            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() - 1, p.getTileY()).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() - 1, p.getTileY()).equals("b")){
                        p.move(-1, 0);
                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));
            }
                }
            }
            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() + 1, p.getTileY()).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() + 1, p.getTileY()).equals("b")){
                        p.move(1, 0);
                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));
            }
            }
            }
            }


        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

}
}
}
```

**Player Class**

```
package Fatman;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player {

    private int tileX, tileY;
    private int dx, dy;

    private Image player; 

    public Player(){

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\FATMANsimplified32xbrown.png");
        player = img.getImage();

        tileX = 12;
        tileY = 18;
    }

    public Image getPlayer(){
        return player;
    }
    public int getTileX(){
        return tileX;
    }
    public int getTileY(){
        return tileY;
    }

    public void move(int dx, int dy){

        tileX += dx;
        tileY += dy;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

well i don't think you could be two thirds of a 3 man group, unless you ate one of your members, but on saying that....
Your question is more suited to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ as its more of a game development question in my opinion.

However.what you could do, is set the candies position offscreen (for example: candy.x = -100;)

on saying that though, where is your game loop?

> public void startGame(){
>
> } public void stopGame(){
>
> } public void update(){ //forces graphics and user input to update the
>   games state }

also consider going to www.java-gaming.org they have awesome tutorials to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in `Player.move()` is eating dots. You have to update the value of variable `Map.Map[]` to keep track of what it's supposed to represent. Otherwise this code is just empty words/symbols that hack at doing one instruction from the programmer at a time but don't use the power of a programming language to let the computer do work according to the conditions it meets.